# create nested object from records oriented dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
[{'Name': 'foo', 'Description': 'foobar', 'Value': '5'}, {'Name': 'baz', 'Description': 'foobaz', 'Value': '4'}, {'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo', 'Value': '8'}]
```

And I'd like to create two nested categories. One category for `Name`, `Description` keys and another category for `Value` key. Example of output for one object:

```
{'details': {'Name': 'foo', 'Description': 'foobar'}, 'stats': { 'Value': '5' }}
```

so far I'm only able to achieve this by joining "manually" each items. I'm pretty sure this is not the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
data = [{'Name': 'foo', 'Description': 'foobar', 'Value': '5'}, {'Name': 'baz', 'Description': 'foobaz', 'Value': '4'}, {'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo', 'Value': '8'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

m = df.to_dict('records')

stats = [{'stats':i.popitem()}  for i in m]

details = [{'details':i} for i in m]

g = list(zip(details,stats))

print(*g)

({'details': {'Name': 'foo', 'Description': 'foobar'}}, {'stats': ('Value', '5')}) ({'details': {'Name': 'baz', 'Description': 'foobaz'}}, {'stats': ('Value', '4')}) ({'details': {'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo'}}, {'stats': ('Value', '8')})
```

The major function here is [popitem()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem), which destructively pulls out a pair from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
from json import dump

result = [{
    'details': {col: row[col] for col in ['Name', 'Description']},
    'stat': {col: row[col] for col in ['Value']}
} for row in df.to_dict(orient='records')]

# Write to file
with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    dump(result, f)
```